# Triggering build information available in child job

Tags: jenkins

I have a job in Jenkins called notification_job which uses the "Build after other projects are built" trigger. The list of jobs will be around 25 and continue to grow. The notification_job needs to know the triggering build's name and build number.

I would like all of the configuration to be done through the notification_job, not through the triggering jobs as that list will grow and become a pain to manage. So how can I retrieve the build name and number in the child job?

Jenkins version is 2.19.3

Thank you,
Duke

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pull the data with a groovy script

```
import hudson.model.Cause

for (cause in build.getCauses()) {
    if (cause instanceof Cause.UpstreamCause) {
        println cause.getUpstreamProject()
        println cause.getUpstreamBuild()
    }
}
```